# Does $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\theta}{1+x^2}\ \mathrm dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus

I'm wondering 
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\theta}{1+x^2}dx$$
equals infinity or just a finite number? Surely when $\theta \geq 1$, it's infinity. But I cannot figure out when less than 1, what will happen.

I think I partially get the answer. Substitute the x with $\tan(t)$, then we get
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan^\theta(t)dt$$, it's infinite for $0<\theta<1$

...actually $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan^\theta(t)dt$$ is not infinite. See Rran Gordon's comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for laughs, let's evaluate this one when $\theta \in (-1,1)$.  The integral may be evaluated by using the residue theorem on the contour integral

$$\oint_C dz \frac{z^{\theta}}{1+z^2}$$

wheere $C$ is a keyhole contour about the positive real axis.  In this case, we have

$$\left ( 1-e^{i 2 \pi \theta}\right ) \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x^{\theta}}{1+x^2} = i 2 \pi \left (\frac{e^{i \pi \theta/2}}{2 i} - \frac{e^{i 3 \pi \theta/2}}{2 i}  \right )$$

or

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x^{\theta}}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2 \cos{(\pi \theta/2)}}$$

Note that the integral blows up when $|\theta|=1$.

Comment: Complex analysis.. I totally forgot all about these staffs..But if substitute the x with $\tan(t)$, then we get
$$\int_0^\infty\tan^\theta(t)dt$$, it's infinite for $0<\theta<1$. Could you help me check why this is wrong?

Comment: $x=\tan{t} \implies dx = \sec^2{t} dt$.

Comment: I mean $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\theta}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\tan^\theta(t)}{1+\tan^2(t)}\sec^2(t)dt=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan^\theta(t)dt$

Comment: seems not wrong

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right.  Not infinite, because the zeroes of the cosine cause behavior as $(x-x_k)^{-\theta}$, where $x_k$ is a zero of the cosine.  This is an integrable singularity when $\theta \in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $-1< \theta < 1$ the integral is finite.  Otherwise, it is not.  If $\theta < -1$ the integral fails to integrate at 0. If $\theta \ge 1$ it fails to integrate at $\infty$.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Can you show me why $-1<\theta<1$ it's finite?

Comment: Suppose $\theta < -1$ At zero we have ${x^\theta\over 1 + x^2}\sim x^\theta$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: At $\infty$ the integrand is $\sim {x^\theta\over x^2}$ This integrates at $\infty$.  At zero, the integrand is $\sim x^\theta$.  This integrates at zero.

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry that I am using all the concept through words,I actually I don't know how to write integral and other symbols
anyway coming to question for 
Theta<(-1)
 use limit comparisons test with g(x)=gamma(theta+1), where gamma is  the function in gamma function,since limit is infinite implies if intrural(g(x)) diverges then given integral diverges,applying condition for gamma function to divergent,from that we get theta<=(-1)
For proving at -1

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE and thank you for your answer! For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation). This may help to format your answer in a way that's easier to understand.